# Как по радиусу или квадрату на Яндекс картах подсчитать количество домов внутри?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, карты, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты

может есть готовы решения или предпосылки к решению. Стоит задача по радиусу или квадрату в яндекс картах определить количество домов внутри.
Алгоритм такой. Расчерчиваешь границы и высвечивается сколько домов внутри этой границы. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас есть данные о количестве домов на карте в каком-то виде, то это можно реализовать.

Если вы хотите получать эти данные через JS API Карт, то таких данных там нет.